# EU passport holder with Belarusian nationality

Tags: airports, check-in, eu-citizens, estonia

I have a European passport issued in Estonia and ID card. In my passport the nationality stated  as Belarusian, as I was born there, but I have been living in Estonia for more than 30 years.

I am going to visit UK and I've checked the requirements online, my ticket says I have to go for a passport/visa checked/stamp. The airline booking form included `nationality` and `country of issued passport` fields, so I entered them as in my passport: `Belarusian`  (nationality) and `Estonia` (country) correspondingly.

I was sure I do not need visa to visit UK as I'm EU passport holder and Estonian citizen which is in EEA.

Comment: Could you clarify what is your citizenship(s) ?. As it is, your post is quite unclear and confusing.

Comment: It is rather unusual (in international terms) for a state to issue a _passport_ to someone they don't consider their own national. Is the passport you have specifically an alien's passport? What does it say in characters 11-13 of the second line in the machine-readable zone?

Comment: Nationality means nothing. If you are Estonian passport holder, then you are an Estonian citizen. That's the main point.

Comment: What do you have in [Citizenship field](https://i.imgur.com/ivTA78n.jpg) in your Estonian passport?

Comment: Do you have dual-nationality because as is you put Belarusian and then you said Estonian citizen? Did you mean Estonian *resident*?

Comment: Sorry , it was a confusion.I have put in when I was checking in online  nationality as Belorusian as it has different meaning to us. I thought if i was born in Belarus my nationality is Belorusian but in my passport stated as  citizenship and nationality  is Estonian as I have EU  passport . I don't have dual citizenshipship . Sorry if my post was not clear. Now everything is fine. I had to call airline and check in again with correct details as in my passport. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Estonian passports don't have a field for `ethnicity`, so therefore the only field that might mention "Belarus" in your Estonian passport should be "7. Sünnikoht / Place of birth / Lieu de naissance". In fact, because citizenship and nationality is the same, Estonian passports don't even have a "nationality" field! So not quite sure where you found Belarus as your nationality in the Estonian passport.... Even if you had an Alien passport issued by Estonia for stateless people, it would probably just say "XXX" in the "3. Kodakondsus / Citizenship / Nationalité" field.

Answer (score 7):

It is a rather common source of misunderstanding in ex-Soviet Union countries. Soviet Union used to state your ethnicity in your passport, and in Russian language it is called "национальность" (natsionalnost). It is a second most typical confusion in ex-USSR immigrant/visa communities after "what should I put into Middle Name field"?

When the English language site asks for your nationality, they are asking for your citizenship (гражданство), and not национальность (etnicity). Thus you put Estonian as your nationality.

Comment: Some Americans also use "nationality" to ask about one's ethnic background.  Confusingly, though, there is also a legal concept of nationality such that all citizens of a country are nationals of that country while the reverse is not necessarily true.  This legal concept of nationality is also distinct from ethnicity, despite the fact that many languages use the cognate of *nationality* to denote *ethnicity.*

Comment: In my personal experience the use of the word "nationality" in various government or travel forms always means "citizenship". But you're right and the legal concept of nationality per se is very unclear in some cases - i.e. there seem to be a large number of British nationals who are not citizens BUT they are eligible for a British passport BUT not considered EU nationals by EU. Go figure...

Comment: The legal concept of nationality is, in many countries at least, distinct from the related concept of citizenship, not synonymous with it.  Some categories of British nationality, for example, do not even come with a right of abode in the United Kingdom, so it's not too surprising that these people are not EU citizens. In Mexican law, as I understand it, citizenship is tied to the right to vote, so everyone under 18 is a non-citizen national. This is the reason why governments often speak of nationality rather than citizenship: it's a broader concept that more accurately reflects requirements.